# Why is the option not selected the second time in multi select list?

Tags: javascript, html

I need to select deselect options in multi-select via JavaScript. The code seems alright but it does not fire the second time you try to select the same item.

So try selecting **Full-Time**, again click it, that will be deselected. Try clicking it again and it won't work.

```js
$('.multi-select option').on('mousedown',function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    selectTop = $(this).parent().scrollTop(); 
    var before = $(this).prop("selected");
    console.warn("before: " + before);
    if (before == true) {
        $(this).prop("selected", false);
    }
    else {
        $(this).attr("selected", "selected");
    }
    console.info("Changed from " + before + " to " + $(this).prop('selected')); 
    mustChangeScrollTop = true;

    return true;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
  
  <head>
    <title>Multi select jquery test</title>
  </head>
  
  <body>
    <select size="6" name="WorkSchedule" multiple="multiple" id="WorkSchedule" class="form-control multi-select">
   <option value="">Select All That Apply</option>
   <option value="4">Full-Time</option>
   <option value="5" >Part-Time</option>
   <option value="6" >Per Diem</option>
   <option value="7">Locum Tenens</option>
  </select>
  </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is a small one; your `else` statement changes the `.attr` value rather than the `.prop` value.

```
else {
    $(this).attr("selected", "selected");
}
```

Attributes and properties, while similar, do not refer to the same underlying value. Here's the working solution, with `.attr` changed to `.prop` in the `else` statement:

```js
$('.multi-select option').on('mousedown',function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    selectTop = $(this).parent().scrollTop(); 
    var before = $(this).prop("selected");
    console.warn("before: " + before);
    if (before == true) {
        $(this).prop("selected", false);
    }
    else {
        $(this).prop("selected", "selected");
    }
    console.info("Changed from " + before + " to " + $(this).prop('selected')); 
    mustChangeScrollTop = true;

    return true;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
  
  <head>
    <title>Multi select jquery test</title>
  </head>
  
  <body>
    <select size="6" name="WorkSchedule" multiple="multiple" id="WorkSchedule" class="form-control multi-select">
   <option value="">Select All That Apply</option>
   <option value="4">Full-Time</option>
   <option value="5" >Part-Time</option>
   <option value="6" >Per Diem</option>
   <option value="7">Locum Tenens</option>
  </select>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: I was stuck on this for so long, this works perfectly. Thanks a lot @freginold :) +1

Answer (score 2):

if i understood what you meant exactly, then this should be what you want with a slitly small change.

```js
$('.multi-select option').on('mousedown',function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    selectTop = $(this).parent().scrollTop(); 
    var before = $(this).prop("selected");
    console.warn("before: " + before);
    if (before == true) {
        $(this).prop("selected", false);
    }
    else {
        $(this).prop("selected", true);  //the change is here
    }
    console.info("Changed from " + before + " to " + $(this).prop('selected')); 
    mustChangeScrollTop = true;

    return true;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
  
  <head>
    <title>Multi select jquery test</title>
  </head>
  
  <body>
    <select size="6" name="WorkSchedule" multiple="multiple" id="WorkSchedule" class="form-control multi-select">
   <option value="">Select All That Apply</option>
   <option value="4">Full-Time</option>
   <option value="5" >Part-Time</option>
   <option value="6" >Per Diem</option>
   <option value="7">Locum Tenens</option>
  </select>
  </body>

</html>
```